# Variable 'test' hides a variale in an enclosing block

Tags: vb.net

i ran into a problem that i cant really explain.

as far as i know if i declare a variable in an if statement it is disposed after the if ends.
but visual studio is telling me its hiding the enclosing block Variable even tho the first declaration 
no longer exists.

am i missing something here ?

to test if it repeats i replicated it in a test project with the following code :

```
    Public Sub New()

        If True Then

            Dim test As String

        End If

        Dim test As String

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a design decision made by the Microsoft team. I got it from [this website](http://www.codepal.co.uk/show/Variable_myVariableName_hides_a_variable_in_an_enclosing_block). They also quote Microsoft Connect as such (their example is similar to yours, but the variable they use is `dt`):

> The help that we give is that users who read the code will never be confused about what "dt" refers to: they won't have to pay careful attention to scope.
>
> But when I do an internet-search for BC30616 or CS0136, I see only requests for help from people who don't understand how to change their code to remove the error.
>
> Personally, I reckon the error is on balance helpful. I bet that if we removed the error, we'd get lots more forum posts with people asking why their code doesn't work...

So, yeah, basically they consider `procedure scope` as one scope where variable naming is concerned, and since the scope "starts" before the `if` they assume that any variable in the outer scope can hide a variable from the inner scope, even if it's declared after the enclosed `if` scope. Of course the procedure won't be run backward, so it shouldn't be a problem, but they did it because they think that they will have less problems with newbies who don't understand how scope works if they signal potential problems that way, while experienced programmers will just fix their code and move on.

Nice find btw.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The error was a bit vague but there reasoning is sound. I temporary worked around in my main project by declaring an object before the if ( I was using 2 different object types) and just cast is when needed. But changing the names to be unique in the scope will also work then.